# Oracle spatial. Starting point of line type feature spatially related to area type feature (sdo_anyinteract)

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I’m trying to select the entity **VAZMC** (area type feature) spatially related to the **Start Point** of **VARAMAL** (line type feature) using oracle spatial.

Please check the following picture for a graphical representation of the entities mentioned above:

[VAZMC and VARAMAL entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWoYN.jpg)

Using the following code:

`select pk.IPID as IPID_VARAMAL, pk.CODIGO_PATRIMONIAL as CODE_VARAMAL, da.IPID as IPID_VAZMC, da.CODIGO_ZMC as CODE_VAZMC from VARAMAL pk, VAZMC da where sdo_anyinteract(da.GEOMETRY, pk.GEOMETRY) = 'TRUE'`

I get the following results (a N:M table)

[sdo_anyinteract spatial operator result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Eyxc.png)

I need to make an equivalent spatial query taking in to account the **Starting point of VARAMAL** so that I would **have always a 1:1 relation** between the 2 entities.

Here’s the equivalent table

[sdo operator desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng16W.png)

Note: I can do this in a GIS environment. First I get the starting point from the line and then use a spatial query to get the desired results.

I would like to do some automation and get the final result in one go, using a sql file (via SQL Plus).

Comment: Pedo, try using sdo_util.extract to get the first element of the line, and use it in you query in place of pk.geometry: sdo_anyinteract(da.geometry, sdo_util.extract(pk.geometry, 1,0))

Comment: Dear gsalem, 
You advice makes perfect sense – thanks a lot.
However, from my tests, I get, unfortunately, the same results.
If a line crosses n areas the spatial query returns n results (1 for each area)
Best regards

Comment: Pedro, ca,n you add your modified SQL?

Comment: select pk.IPID as IPID_VARAMAL, pk.CODIGO_PATRIMONIAL as CODE_VARAMAL, da.IPID as IPID_VAZMC, da.CODIGO_ZMC as CODE_VAZMC from VARAMAL pk, VAZMC da where sdo_anyinteract(da.GEOMETRY, sdo_util.extract(pk.geometry, 1,0)) = 'TRUE'. From the sdo_util.extract documentation i think this function returns geometries that have more than 1 element (which is not the case: it's a 3001 gtype, with only 1 element)

Comment: Pedro, try using getfirstvertex instead, like this :sdo_geometry(2001,null,
sdo_point_type(
sdo_util.getfirstvertex(pk.geometry).X, sdo_util.getfirstvertex(pk.geometry).y,null),
null,null)